# Get uploaded image and attach it to the new post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, uploads

**What I'm doing:**

Publishing a post that has some of it's fields checked via AJAX.

**The problem:**

The images posted are not being saved. All the rest of the infos are. The image is not uploaded to the server.

**What I tried:**

I tried using $_POST, and it was working like that, before I had to check stuff with AJAX, and had to use .preventDefault() and .submit().
Since I had to use AJAX, tried a bunch of stuff, including the fileReader().

**What's being done in the code:**

When the user clicks on the 'submit', I get the fields that have to be checked via JS, pass them with AJAX to PHP, if everything is ok, I return them to the JS and activate the .submit() with the form ID.

**The part of the code that has the 'input=file':**

```
<input class="text-input file-input img_destaque" name="img_destaque" type="file" id="img_destaque" multiple="false" />
<input type="submit" class="btn-pub-ad cadastro-anuncio" id="publicar" name="publicar" value="PUBLICAR">
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'publicar','nonce_anuncio' ); ?>
```

**The part of the code that has the submit button:**

```
<input type="submit" class="btn-pub-ad cadastro-anuncio" id="publicar" name="publicar" value="PUBLICAR">
```

**The part of the code that handles the info and sends via AJAX, using the formData() as sugested in the answers:**

```
function adAnuncio(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = document.getElementById('criar_anuncio');
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append( 'action', 'publicar_anuncio' );
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: clocal.ajaxurl,
        dataType: "html",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        }).success(function (data) {
            $data = $(data);
            $("#mensagem").html($data);
            var anchor = $('#mensagem');
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: anchor.offset().top},'slow');
            if ($('.linha-sucesso').length){
                $('#criar_anuncio').submit();
            }
        });
}
```

**The part of the code that gets what was sent via AJAX and includes the PHP that has the code to create the post:**

```
// if user is logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_publicar_anuncio', 'publish_anuncio');
// if user is not logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_publicar_anuncio', 'publish_anuncio');
function publish_anuncio() {
if ( count( $errors->get_error_messages() ) < 1 ) :
    echo '<div class="linha-sucesso">';
    echo '<img class="ico-sucesso" src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/success-icon.png">';
    echo 'Seu anúncio foi cadastrado correctamente.';
    echo '</div>';
    include 'inc/inserir-anuncios-verificacao.php';
endif;
wp_die();
```

**The part where the file should be handled, stored and attached to the post:**

```
$post_type = 'cadastro_anuncios';
//the array of arguements to be inserted with wp_insert_post
$postStatus = 'publish';
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_status'   => $postStatus, 
    'post_type'     => $post_type,
);
//treating the images
// These files need to be included as dependencies when on the front end.
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
$img_id01 = media_handle_upload( $_POST['img_destaque'], $postID );
update_post_meta($postID, 'img_id01', $img_id01);
```

**It doesnt work. Even if I remove the .submit(), no error is printed or showed on the console. If I keep the .submit() everything gets saved properly except for the images.**

Comment: is the new post correctly created ?

Comment: @mmm Yes, everything works fine. The new post is created, every other field gets saved. Only the image is not working.

Comment: I created a simple plugin which creates a post and uploads a file via ajax. You can find the code at https://github.com/ReneLuecking/formdatatest
To test it, download it as zip, extract the folder into your plugin directory, activate a plugin and create an new page which contains the shortcode [formular]. Now you find a form on that page, where you can create the post

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. Thnx for the help. Or test it and see what I can do. Thnx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the javascript FormData object to upload files via ajax. A simple tutorial is provided [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata). In PHP the file will be available via the globals `$_FILES` and `$_POST`.

---

Additional to the tutorial the WordPress specific data "action" (and maybe "nonce") have to be added to the formData object:

```
formData.append('action', 'add_your_action_here');
// if necessary
formData.append('nonce', 'add_your_nonce_here');
```

Comment: Couldn't make it work. Is that code suposed to work with WordPress?

Comment: Yeah except of the part with xhr. For this you should use $.ajax (like you already did in your code) with type = "POST", url = ajaxurl and data = formData

Comment: Can you check the code I updated? Tried a few ways... None worked.

Comment: In `document.getElementById('the-file');` you have to replace "the-file" with the id of your file input

Comment: Ops, my bad. The code still don't work. Everything is saved and published. But no images in the library, nor attached to the post.

Comment: I have no other idea at the moment. Sorry. Maybe a solution comes in my mind later

Comment: Updated with some info, might help to figure out.

Comment: Tried with that action and nonce. Still nothing. Gonna update my code.

Comment: Tried the plugin. The post and the image are working. Now I have to find out why the form I have isn't working. Will do some tests today.

Comment: Weird thing is: With your plugin, the post and image works. Now, using your plugin as a 'starting point' and building my form... The image upload stops working. I'll post the new code.

Comment: The code is updated. Can you spot any problem?